# PHP: Changing value names for dynamic dropdown menus

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm sorry for the very basic question, but I rarely use PHP and can't figure out how to do something simple. Thanks so much in advance for your help.

I created a drop-down menu that automatically displays the folders in a directory. I use the variable (var) that stores this information to name each dropdown selection, but it shows the entire directory path.

How do I edit my code to display only the last folder in the directory path, instead of the full path?

```
<select name="myDirs">
<option value="" selected="selected">Lab</option>
<?php
$dirs = glob("/var/www/html/blast/labs/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($dirs as $val){
echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

Which returns a dropdown that gives, for example, the following options: 
/var/www/html/blast/lab/Smith
/var/www/html/blast/lab/Jones

And instead, I'd just like the drop-down options to be: 
Smith
Jones

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [basename()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.basename.php), change:

```
...
echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
...
```

to

```
...
echo '<option value="'.basename($val).'">'.basename($val)."</option>\n";
...
```

Comment: That works perfectly, and you couldn't have explained it any better. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will return the last part after the /:

```
 substr($val, strrpos($val, '/'));
```